# Network mapped drive is not accessible

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a problem while mapping a network I am getting the error `(Z:is not accessible Access is denied)`

Everything was working till yesterday, but today that drive is not accessible.
I used below command

```
icacls z:\ /setowner "Administrators" /T /C from cmd with Admin privillage

(z:\: Access is denied
z:\* Access is denied
)
```

This is only from single computer, from the rest i can access it.

Any idea? Please

I cannot add solution now (I disabled my firewall and all is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled Kaspersky firewall and it worked.